# updating list of objects in python

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to implement in Python "image evolution" algorithm, like this: http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/

I wonder how to write an efficient fitness-calculating function of the current screen,  with regard to the target screen. My present fitness function uses pygame.surfarray.array3d(source), but the program is very very slow even for small images.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`surfarray` uses [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/) (or numeric) as backend, that means you can use numpy operations to imporove performance. As an example, if you need to compute the xor between two arrays, instead of computing the xor of every position you can use: `numpy.bitwise_xor(arr1, arr2, arr_result)`